# sed replace between symbols > and <

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to remove the characters between the > symbol and the < symbol as shown below and replace with the IP address 8.8.8.8

```
<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">J_jRQtEolDEurgAVIwwwADXaZQs_</value>
```

I've tried the following with sed first to remove the characters

```
 sed -i "/CLIENTPREFIX/s/\b>*.\b>//" name.sh
```

and then use a separate command to add the IP adress

Can some one help in combining both the commands to one command?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.*` instead of `*.` and also the second symbol in your regex is wrong it must be `<`

```
sed "/CLIENTPREFIX/s/>[^<>]*</>$ip</g" file
```

or

```
$ echo '<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">J_jRQtEolDEurgAVIwwwADXaZQs_</value>' | sed "/CLIENTPREFIX/s/>.*</>$ip</"
<value name="CLIENTPREFIX"></value>
```

Comment: Thank you. How do I add the IP between > and <?

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed and variables:

```
CP="CLIENTPREFIX"
IP="8.8.8.8"
sed -E -i 's/("'"$CP"'">)[^<]*(<)/\1'"$IP"'\2/' name.sh
```

Output to file name.sh:

```
<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">8.8.8.8</value>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo can capture the groups found by a regex

```
sed -i "s/\(<value.*>\).*\(<\/value>\)/\18.8.8.8\2/g" name.sh
```

**Explanation:**

Everything between `\(` and `\)` will be consider a group, that you can then use by `\1`, `\2`, etc (depending on the number of groups you defined).
The first part `\(<value.*>\).*\(<\/value>\)` stores in the first group the value `<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">` and in the second group the value `</value>`.
The second part replaces everything that matched, by the content of the first group, followed by the 8.8.8.8, folowed by the content of the second group, transforming the line 
`<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">J_jRQtEolDEurgAVIwwwADXaZQs_</value>` 
into 
`<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">8.8.8.8</value>`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sed 's/\(CLIENTPREFIX">\)[^<]*/\18.8.8.8/' file
<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">8.8.8.8</value>
```

or if you need the ip addr in a variable and assuming `ip='8.8.8.8'` is set somewhere earlier:

```
$ sed 's/\(CLIENTPREFIX">\)[^<]*/\1'"$ip"'/' file
<value name="CLIENTPREFIX">8.8.8.8</value>
```